# Windows GIT using HTTPS client auth from smartcard token

Tags: windows, git, smartcard, cac

On Windows, how does one configure GIT to prompt or otherwise use a client HTTPS certificate when connecting to an HTTPS repository that requires HTTPS Client authentication?

Complications:

1. SSL is blocked by firewalls, can't sidestep the problem.
2. Private Key is locked onto smart card, cannot extract or replace.

Comment: If you mean: a card-generated *ssl* certificate, I don't know that you can do this at all. If you mean instead: a card-generated *auth token for login* over https using a static certificate, you'll just need to write your own Git credential manager that defers to the smart-card.

Comment: This kind of client authentication: https://www.jscape.com/blog/client-certificate-authentication
PKCS12, but the private key is kept on a smart card and the smart card does all of the heavy lifting with it, so the host never sees the private key either.  I cannot extract it.  The web server is requiring it prior to GitLab doing any of its authentication.

Comment: OK, they're talking about the TLS handshake and talking about setting up plugins for browsers where the plugin takes over the entire handshake process. Git uses the OS's `libcurl` library to do the TLS handshake (not a browser), so you'll be dependent on whether the OS's `libcurl` as used in Git even *allows* this kind of intercession in the first place. Interposing arbitrary software like this is tricky (and has OS-level security implications; browsers can get away with it by being their own separate ecosystems). You'll need a serious Windows expert here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    git clone -c http.sslCert="CurentUser\MY\[thumbprint of cert]" [URL]
```

Or
.gitconfig:

```
    [http]
        sslCert=CurrentUser\\MY\\[thumbprint of cert]
```

PS, for CURL, it is --cert or -K "CurrentUser\MY[thumbprint]"

Comment: Found the path needed from the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386742/failed-to-get-certificate-location-in-libcurl

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that [IMarvinTPA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9452984/imarvintpa)'s answer worked great for me, I did have to do one other thing however:

`.gitconfig`

```
[http]
sslbackend = schannel
sslCert=CurrentUser\\MY\\[thumbprint of cert]
```

**EDIT**: Sorry I did not have the reputation to just comment on the answer

Comment: Good catch, I always defaulted to schannel.  I think in some documentation I wrote later, I had that as a critical part though.

This also works for soft-certs if you have them, just a little easier to work with.